# A phrase to validate one's awareness (or knowledge) about some event

Tags: phrase-request

I am looking for a phrase to validate other person's awareness about something in a formal and polite way, like:

> "Your alarm went off and disarmed right after. Are you aware of this?"

Or:

> "Someone disabled your security system through the dashboard just now. Did this happen within your knowledge?"

I usually make calls with institutional customers and both examples sound like I am missing something.

I would be most grateful if I could find a phrase that is more suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For informational messages such as your examples, I would always suggest depersonalising the content of the message so as to convey the message in a technical tone without implying a cause (which may not be known).

For example, in your second phrase, rather than stating:

> '*Someone* disabled your security system through the dashboard just now.'

I would instead suggest:

> Your security system has been disabled through the dashboard, please confirm that you authorised this action.

Since this is evidently some form of computerised security system, an action such as the above has the potential to be caused by a benign system malfunction. Hence, without depersonalising the corresponding informational message, the user may immediately feel compromised and could then be upset should the warning transpire to be a false alarm.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways that you can introduce a query of this kind, such as:

> May I/we draw your attention to.....?
>
> Please be aware that.....
>
> Are you aware that...?
>
> Will you kindly confirm that......
>
> You may need to take urgent action following ....

There is no set formula and it's really just a matter of context and of preference.